# How to make properly horizontally aligned a (\vbox) vertical box (\box_use) used in a corresponding environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, expl3

Suppose I define a (`\vbox`) vertical box in order, in one hand, to compute the height of its content and, in the other hand, to (`\box_use`) use its content. The following MCE (that doesn't involve the height computation) points out using such a box in e.g. a `center` environment doesn't center the content's box (by contrast, the same content directly put in a `\vbox:n {...}` is centered).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {
  Foo
  \par
  bar
}
\box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
\par
\begin{center}
  \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \vbox:n {
    Foo
    \par
    bar
  }
\end{center}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Do you understand why a (`\vbox`) vertical box `\box_use`d in a `center` environment isn't centered and how to make it centered? Obviously, the question is analogous for a `flushright` environment.

Comment: That's standard TeX behavior and `\vbox:n` is essentially just the same as `\vbox` (plus color protection). You want `\leavevmode`. You can also observe that in the first case there's no indentation.

Comment: @egreg OK. Wouldn't `\mode_leave_vertical:` be more `LaTeX3`ish? :) Anyway, if you make your comment an answer, I could accept it.